# Qt login code not working correctly

Tags: database, qt, sqlite, authentication

```
void admin::on_login_a_clicked()
{
    QString usr,pass;
    usr = ui->Au->text();
    pass = ui->Ap->text();
   // usr.toStdString() ;
   // pass.toStdString() ;
    qDebug() << usr;
    QSqlQuery sq;
    if(sq.exec("select username,password from admin as a where a.username  ='"+ usr +"'"))
    {

        ui->con->setText("Logged in successfully");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->con->setText("Login Failure");
    }
}
```

I have connected the data sq lite db and wrote this query from the internet I have no idea about any feature of Qt so it there is syntactical mistake or any other kind of please tell. The problem with this code is that it keeps logging in even if the 'usr' is not in database.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: yes i was doing that but that is not the issue because username is unique

Comment: You also should not use string concatenation to form an SQL query, especially not if part of that string is user input.
Use `QSqlQuery::prepare()` and value binding instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sq.exec() doesn't indicate whether there is a returned record or not, rather it returns true/false to indicate if the query executed successfully or not (that's always true in your case since the execution is always successful).

to navigate through the query's results, you need to use sq.next(). In your case, sq.next() will return false if the username doesn't exist. Otherwise, it will return true.

change

```
if(sq.exec("select username,password from admin as a where a.username  ='"+ usr +"'")){ //user exists }
```

to

```
sq.exec("select username,password from admin as a where a.username  ='"+ usr +"'"));
if (sq.next()) { //user exists }
```

Comment: can you please explain this?

Comment: Please don't concatenate SQL query parameters in the statement yourself. That's what prepared statements are for, use `QSqlQuery::prepare` and `QSqlQuery::bindValue`.